# Count score in Snake game made in Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I made a snake game using jQuery. Now I want to add score to that. I've added a variable "score" and incremented it everytime the snake eats food and tried to print it on console, but all I'm getting is "NaN". Someone please help me to get the score correctly...

Since it can't be posted with less text when the code is huge, I'm typing all these meaningless words. Please forgive me for this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   init();
});
var score;
var move;
function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    createSnake();
    food.createFood();
}

function play() {
    $('.newGame').hide();
    $('.playgame').hide();
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
}

function gameover() {
 console.log(score);
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').show();
}

function playGame() {
score=0;
    $('#gameboard').empty();
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
}

var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
            var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');
            
            for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
                var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
                $(row).append(col);
            }
            $("#gameboard").append(row);
        }
    }
}

var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
};

function createSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
    snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
}

function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        if (event.which == 38) {
            snake.direction = 'u';
        } else if (event.which == 39) {
            snake.direction = 'r';
        } else if (event.which == 40) {
            snake.direction = 'd';
        } else if (event.which == 37) {
            snake.direction = 'l';
        }
    });
}

function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');
    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
        x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
        y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
        x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
        y = y - 1;
    }
    
    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
        console.log('true');
        score= score+10;
        console.log(score);
        $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
        snake.position.push(tail);
        food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
        gameover();
        return;
    
    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
        gameover();
        return;
    }
    
    move=setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
}

var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM-1)) + 1;
        var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
        $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
        food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
}

function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<style>
.buttonnewgame {
     position: relative;
}

.newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
     font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}
.instructions
{
margin-left: 5px;
float: left;
position : relative;
color: #c603fc;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.gameContainer{
    width:100%;
}

#gameboard {
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:3px;
}

.playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
       
}

/* styling the board */
div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

div[class*='col']{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

/*display the snake*/
.snake {

    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
}

.food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div class="game">
    <div class="buttonnewgame">
       <center><input type="button" name="New game" value="New game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
        <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button></center> 
        <div class="gameContainer">
      
            <div id="gameboard">
                <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div></div></td>
        <td width="150">
    <div class="instructions" >
      OBJECT: Get as many pieces of "food" as possible using your arrow keys.  Each time you do this, you will grow.   You want to try to get as big as possible without crashing into a wall or back onto yourself.  Good Luck!!
      </div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I am seeing the score increment correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`score` was originally `undefined` because you didn't give it a value when you declared it.

Adding 10 to `undefined` is obviously `NaN`.

Instead, declare `score` like so: `var score = 0;`.

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    init();
  });
  var score = 0;
  var move;

  function init() {
    board.initBoard();
    createSnake();
    food.createFood();
  }

  function play() {
    $('.newGame').hide();
    $('.playgame').hide();
    moveSnake();
    getSnakeDir();
  }

  function gameover() {
    console.log(score);
    clearTimeout(move);
    $('.newGame').show();
  }

  function playGame() {
    score = 0;
    $('#gameboard').empty();
    $('.newGame').hide();
    init();
    play();
  }

  var board = {
    DIM: 20,
    initBoard: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < board.DIM; i++) {
        var row = $('<div class="row-' + i + '"></div>');

        for (var j = 0; j < board.DIM; j++) {
          var col = ('<div class="col-' + j + '-' + i + '"></div>');
          $(row).append(col);
        }
        $("#gameboard").append(row);
      }
    }
  }

  var snake = {
    position: ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'],
    direction: 'r',
    speed: 200,
  };

  function createSnake() {
    $('.col-10-10').addClass('snake');
    $('.col-11-10').addClass('snake');
    snake.position = ['10-10', '10-11', '10-12'];
  }

  function getSnakeDir() {
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      //event.preventDefault();
      if (event.which == 38) {
        snake.direction = 'u';
      } else if (event.which == 39) {
        snake.direction = 'r';
      } else if (event.which == 40) {
        snake.direction = 'd';
      } else if (event.which == 37) {
        snake.direction = 'l';
      }
    });
  }

  function moveSnake() {
    var tail = snake.position.pop();
    $('.col-' + tail).removeClass('snake');
    var coords = snake.position[0].split('-');
    var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
    var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

    if (snake.direction == 'r') {
      x = x + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'd') {
      y = y + 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'l') {
      x = x - 1;
    } else if (snake.direction == 'u') {
      y = y - 1;
    }

    var currentcoords = x + '-' + y;
    snake.position.unshift(currentcoords);

    $('.col-' + currentcoords).addClass('snake');

    //when snake eats food
    if (currentcoords == food.coords) {
      console.log('true');
      score = score + 10;
      console.log(score);
      $('.col-' + food.coords).removeClass('food');
      snake.position.push(tail);
      food.createFood();
    }

    //game over
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > board.DIM || y > board.DIM) {
      gameover();
      return;

    }

    //if snake touch itself
    if (hitItself(snake.position) == true) {
      gameover();
      return;
    }

    move = setTimeout(moveSnake, 200);
  }

  var food = {
    coords: "",

    createFood: function() {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM - 1)) + 1;
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (board.DIM - 1)) + 1;
      var fruitCoords = x + '-' + y;
      $('.col-' + fruitCoords).addClass('food');
      food.coords = fruitCoords;
    },
  }

  function hitItself(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      var value = array[i];
      if (value in valuesSoFar) {
        return true;
      }
      valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
<style>
  .buttonnewgame {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .newGame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
  }
  
  .instructions {
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    color: #c603fc;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .gameContainer {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #gameboard {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 3px;
  }
  
  .playgame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    font: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #FF69B4;
  }
  /* styling the board */
  
  div[class^='row'] {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  div[class*='col'] {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  /*display the snake*/
  
  .snake {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  
  .food {
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="game">
        <div class="buttonnewgame">
          <center><input type="button" name="New game" value="New game" class="newGame" style="display:none;" onclick="playGame()" />
            <button class="playgame" onclick="play()">Play Game</button></center>
          <div class="gameContainer">

            <div id="gameboard">
              <!-- snake game in here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <div class="instructions">
        OBJECT: Get as many pieces of "food" as possible using your arrow keys. Each time you do this, you will grow. You want to try to get as big as possible without crashing into a wall or back onto yourself. Good Luck!!
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```